# event is not able pass to the function in jquery trigger click event

Tags: jquery

I have below check box in each row of td cell and on select/click of check box am calling a function and passing event to the function. But When trigger the checkbox click event from jquery ex: `$('#chkresult').trigger('click')`the event is going as undefined to the calling function.

```
<INPUT id=chkresult class="imscheckbox imsenabled dt_res_check" onclick=filterResults.rowCheckboxClick(event) name=chkresult value=true type=checkbox jQuery18308359171494640825="1519">
```

please help me out in this as soon as possible

Comment: Try once with `$('#chkresult').get(0).click()`

Comment: @KarthikSivakumar, if paste the same line of HTML into any view of html page, it will be corrected by own once it will be render into browser. could you please confirm what is the syntax error in above code????

Comment: Answer by @reddy solves all the syntax error.

Comment: @KarthikSivakumar, that's okay but my option is if you paste the above code in HTML, wil it work or not? have to checked it?  i have checked this and it is rendering in correct way..

Comment: The code what ever rendered in the browser i took it and when we click of check box from html (ui) it's working fine.

Comment: $('#chkresult').get(0).click() is works perfect to me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You have many typo error int he line

```
<INPUT id=chkresult class="imscheckbox imsenabled dt_res_check" 
onclick=filterResults.rowCheckboxClick(event) name=chkresult value=true 
type=checkbox jQuery18308359171494640825="1519">
```

it should be

```
<input id="chkresult" class="imscheckbox imsenabled dt_res_check" 
onclick="filterResults.rowCheckboxClick(event)" name="chkresult" 
value="true" type="checkbox" jQuery18308359171494640825="1519">
```

if you notice there are many missing `""` and the word `input` is in Capitals

---

**Suggestion:** It is not recommended to use the inline event binders anymore. Its better if you maintain separation of the code. So what I would suggest is to remove the `onclick="filterResults.rowCheckboxClick(event)"` part from the Html and bind the click event using jquery on document ready as below.

```
$(function(){  // short hand of $(document).ready(function(){..
  $('#chkresult').on('click',filterResults.rowCheckboxClick(event));
});
```

This way we keep the HTML and Jquery codes separate and thus helps in maintenance.

Comment: Ram singh sorry we both edited at the same time and mine overwrote yours, thanks for the effort

Comment: no worries.. main idea was to correct the format.. :)